# Waring: illegal string offset in 'name' in contactform since PHP7.1

Tags: php, php-7.1

Since the update to php7.1 I get an error on a contactform. Downgrading is not an option. Any solution? I tried some thing I found, but doesn't seem to work what I change.

The message I get is "Warning: illegal string offset in 'name'" and it does this for all the values in the form (name, email, message,...).

```
<?php
require_once("classes/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");

$smarty_mail = new Smarty;
$smarty_mail->template_dir = 'templates/mail';
$smarty_mail->compile_dir  = 'pages/templates_c';

if ( isset($_POST['submit']) )
{
    $error = '';
    print_r($error);
    if (!trim($_POST['name'])) $error['name']=true;
    if (!check_email($_POST['email']))  $error['email']=true;
    if (!trim($_POST['message'])) $error['message']=true;
    if (!isset($_POST['privacypolicy'])) $error['privacypolicy']=true;
    $_POST['name'] = stripslashes($_POST['name']);
    $_POST['message'] = stripslashes($_POST['message']);

    if (!$error)
    {   
        $contact = $_POST;
        $contact['ip'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];               
        $contact['host'] = gethostbyaddr( $contact['ip']);

        $smarty_mail->assign("contact", $contact);  
        $message = $smarty_mail->fetch("mail_contact.tpl.html");

        $subject = "contactformulier";
        if( sendemail(MAIL_FROM_NAME, MAIL_FROM, $_POST['name'], $_POST['email'], $subject, $message, "HTML", "", ""))
        {
            $smarty->assign("send", true);  
        }

    }
    $smarty->assign("error",$error);
    $smarty->assign("set", $_POST);
}
$main_content_template = "contact.tpl.html";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$error = '';
```

makes no sense. You're initializing `$error` as a string, but then you're accessing it as if it were an array:

```
    $error['name']=true;
```

It should probably be

```
$error = array();
```

instead.

Comment: That is one of the things I tried, that $error = array(); but it did the same :/

Comment: Ok, it does work lol. It was some sort of caching why the error kept coming. Just tried it again and it works now :)

Comment: @diegie Yet [that's exactly the problem](https://3v4l.org/QIFdb). You may have other instances of `$error` being incorrectly handled as string.

Comment: Ah no it does not. When the form is submitted, I get an empty page with only Array ( ) on it.

Comment: @diegie Then you'll have to look at the rest of your code (e.g. your templates).